# Unable to run Tango java_basic_examples in Google Tango device

Tags: java, android, tango

I am trying to build the tango 'java_basic_examples' and trying to run 'hello_area_description', 'hello_depth_perception' and 'hello_motion_tracking' samples. I am able to build all the samples but when I tried to run on Tango device I am getting below exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projecttango.examples.java.helloareadescription/com.projecttango.examples.java.helloareadescription.StartActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.tango/com.google.atap.tango.RequestPermissionActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I searched in the whole project and didn't found this Activity. Could you please help me to resolve this problem and move ahead with Tango application development.

Comment: Well we have no code so no, we really can't.  We have no idea what Tango is.  But a call to that activity is obviously in there so I'd take another look at either the code or your setup missing some code you need.

Comment: You tagged your question "**tango**", which is "_an open-source software library for D programming language_".I think you should tag it "**google-project-tango**", which is "_a hardware and software platform which brings 3D environmental sensing to Android devices. It offers six degree of freedom motion tracking, area learning, and depth perception capabilities._"

Comment: We have the same problem here, too. On which device does it occur ? The applications used to work on the Yellowstone tablet (I cannot make sure in order not to break the installed application), but on Phab 2 Pro it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use the correct branch when checking out the examples from GitHub. I could solve the problem by a fresh checkout of the release/biyelgee branch in the tango examples. That way the appropriate sample app seems to be used.